# Java-how to split one list in two lists

Tags: java

Who can help me and give me a code that split an list contains positif and negatif values in two list :the first list contains neagtif values and second list contains positf values without using java library.help me

Comment: So your previous question was deleted and you created new account to ask exacly same question?

Answer (score 0):

**Why not a little help!**

*Assuming your List contains integers.*

```
List<Integer> integers = listOfIntegers();
List<Integer> positive = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> negative = new ArrayList<>();

for (Integer i : integers) {
    if (i >= 0) 
        positive.add(i);
    else
        negative.add(i);
}
```

The next time you need to specify more information. Furthermore, you must ask about a particular problem in your code and not for a complete solution.